# Get if customer is activated

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer

How can I check if the customer has activated his account on the order success page.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
<?php if(Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('confirmation', array('notnull' => true)): ?>
    <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>

          stuff here

    <?php else: ?>

          other stuff here

<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?>
```

And...

```
    <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() || ($session->getCustomer()->getCustomerActivated())): ?>

stuff here

            <?php else: ?>

                  other stuff here

        <?php endif; ?>
```

both don't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First it's important to say that if the customer is logged in the account is activated.

Now for your checks you need the customer model. You can try to get that from the session (but usually you will have it only when the customer is logged in as far as I know) or load it by the order email. The customer model has two methods for checking if a customer needs confirmation. Here is some code:

```
//get the customer from session
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

//or load customer by order email
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());

if ( $customer->getId() && $customer->isConfirmationRequired() && $customer->getConfirmation()){
     //customer account needs to be confirmed
} else if ($customer->getId()){
     //customer is confirmed
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't get it to work on my checkout success page.

Comment: Do you have the correct customer email? In my example I used `$order` variable, please make sure that you have the actual order loaded there. Usually it should be available on checkout success.Please check that the customer is loaded (dump some data about customer in logfile)